# Iterating over a list defined in Value.yaml in Chart.yaml

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, kubernetes-helm

I am not able to use helm range inside Chart.yaml file. I have a general chart for peer nodes and i want to create aliases for it based on the number of children of a list defined in values.yaml.

I tried Helm range but it seems i can't use it in Chart.yaml. So are there any other solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Chart.yaml` file is not evaluated with `values.yaml`, so it's not possible to do it in any Helm way.

Please check these resources for more details:

- https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/10887
- https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2205

Comment: Even if it did, I don't think we can use functions in chart. Yaml , but yeah after trying i gave up and creates aliases manually, which isn't the worst thing since i already add to my list manually.